# How can I do this program with arrays?

Tags: java

I have a doubt with a problem about arrays, I have array that only recieves 1 and 0, for example {0,1,0,1,0}, after that I need to select 2 positions inside of the array, in this case p1 = 0 and p2=2, then I need to print the number between p1 and p2, in this case 010, after that I need convert that numer to decimal, how can I do that? Im a beginner, really I tried but I can't did it

Comment: Seems like school assignment to me, please show us your efforts on how you tried to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't give you the ready solution but an idea how you can achieve this.

Think if a loop that iterates from p1 till p2 through your array. In each iteration it prints out the value of the array at its current position.

Hint: for loops are perfectly suitable for this. To print use

```
System.out.println(array[currentPosition])
```

To compute the decimal value you would contain a variable in which you compute like this. 
Initially the variable `decimal` gets set to 0.

If the value of the array at its `currentPosition` is 1 you take the value of `decimal` times 2 and add 1 and again save it in decimal.

If it is zero you take `decimal` times two.